# Passing variable Timestamp with JSON in POSTMAN

Tags: java, json, postman, jackson-databind

I have a field named `acceptance_time` in the database:

[image]

And I want to add new order using the POST method in postman.
This is my code in java:

```
 @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS", timezone="Europe/Berlin")
    @Column
    private Timestamp acceptanceTime;
```

---

When I send the request from the postman, I am getting this error.

[image]

---

It says:Cannot parse date \"2018-09-13 18:41:02.36\": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ',

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced this issue sometime back. In my case, upgrading the Jackson version to `2.9.2` had fixed the issue. In your Pom.xml, look for the Jackson dependency and change the version to 2.9.2.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This might help, please check once.

Comment: ah, Okay. There must be some way by which this dependency is coming. Or are you using any other Jackson dependency?